# Alternative to IOUtils.toString() for large streams?

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I'm getting a large response stream back from an HTTP request.  It's JSON, so I need to convert it to a string for processing.  I'm running out of heap space on the call to toString.

Code is as follows:

```
URLConnection conn = new URL(url + "?query=" + URLEncoder.encode(sparql, "UTF-8") + "&output=JSON").openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
InputStream respStream = conn.getInputStream();
response = IOUtils.toString(respStream, "UTF-8");
respStream.close();
```

I've tried setting the heap size as large as I can. I can't get the data in smaller chunks easily (but if there's not a better choice, I'll implement that).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you use a library that parses the JSON for you?

Comment: I do - once I have it in string format.

Comment: You can't pass that InputStream instead of the String?

Comment: you can try reading the InputStream by read() and store it in StringBuilder.

Comment: If you can't store the full `String` in memory, you can't store the full `String` in memory; there's not going to be a way around that.

Comment: try this link maybe it will help: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-string-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

I wound up just requesting the data in smaller chunks, which I should have just done to begin with.  This was kind of a stupid question, thanks for taking the time to look at it.